# when I use nio, serverSocket.accept() throws IllegalBlockingModeException

Tags: java, nio

When I code like this:

```
ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
InetSocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress("localhost",8888);
ssc.socket().bind(sa);
ssc.configureBlocking(false);
ssc.socket().accept();
```

the `ServerSocket.accept()` method throws `java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException`. Why can't I call `accept()`, even though I set blocking to `false`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are calling `ssc.socket().accept()`, not `ssc.accept()`. If you change the last line to `ssc.accept()` then it will work as expected, which is to return a SocketChannel if one is waiting or null if not.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what javadoc for serversocket.accept() says?

IllegalBlockingModeException - if this socket has an associated channel, and the channel is in non-blocking mode.

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc specifically states that `ServerSocketChannel.accept()`:

> Accepts a connection made to this channel's socket.
>
> If this channel is in non-blocking mode then this method will immediately
>   return null if there are no pending connections. Otherwise it will block
>   indefinitely until a new connection is available or an I/O error occurs.

The general idea is:

- If you want to block while waiting for incoming connections, you leave the server socket in blocking mode. If you're writing a server that has nothing to do until a connection actually comes in, then blocking mode is what you want.
- If you want to do other things, and periodically check to see whether there's a pending connection, you want non-blocking mode.

Blocking mode is the default for a reason: Most servers don't want to poll their accepting socket for incoming connections.