# Java nio SocketChannel failed to create

Tags: java, sockets, selector, nio, channel

I've got this:

```
Selector selector = Selector.open();
ServerSocketChannel listenChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
listenChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(12112));
listenChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
```

Just 4 lines of code inside main(), and the last line throws out exception:

```
java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.register(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:201)
at java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel.register(SelectableChannel.java:280)
at myServer.main(myServer.java:18)
```

I just wish to create a ServerSocketChannel and register it to a Selector. What's wrong here, how to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328925/when-i-use-nio-serversocket-accept-throws-illegalblockingmodeexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try turning off the blocking mode by:
`listenChannel.configureBlocking(false);`